# Read the property of Object through Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am trying to extract the price value from the object text. I receive undefined value. Please any suggestion.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

console.log('1. lets start')
fetch('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=DOGEUSD')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
     
      console.log(text['price']);



    })
```

Comment: `text` is a string, not an object. It has no `.price` property.

Comment: If the data you're fetching is JSON, then use `res.json()` in place of `res.text()` and then you will get an object, but only if the data you're fetching is actually JSON to start with.  People can only really help you if you do a `console.log(text)` and show us what the data actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be res.json() not text()

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

console.log('1. lets start')
fetch('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=DOGEUSD')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(text => {
      console.log(text['price']);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the text() to json(), in order to obtain a json object:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

console.log('1. lets start')
fetch('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=DOGEUSD')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res['price']);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The url you refer to, returns json, not text, as advised by other answers.

On top of that, you can use a nicer syntax of `text.price` instead of `text['price']`

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

console.log('1. lets start')
fetch('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=DOGEUSD')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(text => {
      console.log(text.price);
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking for JSON.parse(). E.g.:

```
fetch('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=DOGEUSD')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
      const myObject = JSON.parse(text);
      console.log(myObject['price']);
    })
```